# static Map as cache loses or doesn't set values

Tags: java, caching, dictionary, static, tomcat7

my environment is a web application running in Tomcat 7 and one of my frontend handlers retrieves some integers from a database for some purpose. During different requests of different users the same integers may be retrieved, that's why I wanted to add a simple Map as a static field in my handler to cache already read integers.

The problem now is that during requests I found that some values are cached, others not. It seems that some put-calls to the map are simply ignored or the values don't get stored or whatever. If I debug the application in Eclipse I can see that the calls to put are accessed, but afterwards the newly fetched value is not part of the Cache, at least Eclipse doesn't show it. If the last fetched values needs to be fetched twice during the same request, the second call clearly hits the cache and avoids access to the database, even though Eclipse doesn't show the needed values as part of the cache. If the same value is needed in another request, the value again is first fetched from the database, stored in the cache, not shown by Eclipse, but available for retrieval within the same request.

I'm really lost here, seems like I'm doing something very wrong. But I already have other static fields in my web application as caches and doesn't see such strange behavior with those. But those are no Maps, only custom or Integer objects.

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> dirsOwnerCache = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
private static Map<Integer, Integer> docsOwnerCache = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();

public static void someMethod()
{
    [...]
    Integer ownerId = null;
    sync: synchronized(tabelle.equals("ordner") ? Util.dirsOwnerCache : Util.docsOwnerCache)
    {
        ownerId = tabelle.equals("ordner") ?    Util.dirsOwnerCache.get(dsid) :
                                                Util.docsOwnerCache.get(dsid);
        if (ownerId != null)
        {
            break sync;
        }

        // fetching from database
        [...]
        ownerId = rs.getInt("besitzer_id");
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

        if (tabelle.equals("ordner"))
        {
            Util.dirsOwnerCache.put(dsid, ownerId);
        }
        else
        {
            Util.docsOwnerCache.put(dsid, ownerId);
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

I would appreciate any hints where I could look for the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what the problem is: My environment is a bit special as my web application consists of a Servlet/JSP-Frontend and an Axis 2 SOAP-service as backend. To optionally get rid of SOAP we decided to make the Axis 2 service available as a native Java class using some ClassLoader manipulations, especially using URLClassLoader with paths to our backends and all the libs we use etc. and load backend classes natively using URLClassLoader. java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass says that normally findLoadedClass is used before a class is loaded to see if it already has been loaded before and don't load it again. This doesn't seem to be the case in my environment or how I use URLClassLoader, because each invocation to load a class during each request produced a new class object. Because of this the static field were newly created during the requests. Though I don't know why it seemed in Eclipse that some values of my caches were persistent during requests, maybe some loaded classes got cached by URLClassLoader somehow.

However, I added my own static map as cache for once loaded classes before using URLClassLoader and now my backend caches work like expected: Their values persist during requests and are properly visible in Eclipse debugger.